# Error says there is no routes, but it seems there is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested

I have the following form declaration :

```
<%= semantic_form_for @contrat_line, 
    :url => url_for(:controller =>"/backend/orders/#{@contrat.id}/contrat_lines", 
        :action =>"create") do |f| %>
```

I want to hit the following route :

```
POST    /backend/orders/:order_id/contrat_lines(.:format)   backend/contrat_lines#create
```

but i have the following error when i want to display the form (even before using it):

```
No route matches {:controller=>"backend/orders/23/contrat_lines", :action=>"create"}
```

I would say this route exist, why is it saying that it does not?

Comment: something is wrong: `orders/#{@contrat.id}` but `orders/:order_id`

Comment: I already tried it, errors becomes :
    No route matches {:controller=>"backend/orders/:order_id/contrat_lines", :action=>"create"}

Comment: are you sure about the spelling of `contrat`? Seems you are missing a `c` there.

Comment: not in my language, i know i should have done it in english.

Answer (score 1):

routes.rb code

```
match "/backend/orders/:order_id/contrat_lines" => "orders#contrat_lines", :as => "contrat_lines"
```

then, view code

```
<%= semantic_form_for @contrat_line, 
    :url => contrat_lines_url(:order_id => @contrat.id), 
        :action =>"create") do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to salil i devised the following form :

backend_order_contrat_lines_url(:order_id => @contrat.id), :action =>"create" do |f| %>

And it works with thoses routes :

```
namespace :backend do
    resources :orders do
      resources :contrat_lines
    end
end
```

Thx a lot!, if you want i can edit your answer and set it as accepted.